# Does continuity equation applies for magnetic charge and magnetic current?

Tags: magnetic-flux, continuity

I wonder if, since we are capable of defining a charge and some magnetic currents, we can apply the continuity equation to them in such a way that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \rho_{\text{mag}}}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{M} = 0
\end{equation}

With **M** being the magnetic current density. The thing is that since we understand magnetic charge and magnetic current density as merely mathematical tools, I'm not quite sure about this relationship.